# An error occurred while trying to connect with the sphero

Tags: java, android, sphero-api, sphero

can someone can identify the error in this code, the logic of the program itself is not implemented, it should just connect with the sphero, then no error should not occur.
does anyone know how to solve this

Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivitySimon extends Activity 
{
    private SpheroConnectionView mSpheroConnectionView;
    private Sphero mRobot = null;

    private void updateSpheroPosition(double x, double y)
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_simon);

        mSpheroConnectionView = (SpheroConnectionView)     findViewById(R.id.sphero_connection_view);
        mSpheroConnectionView.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Robot robot) 
            {
                //SpheroConnectionView is made invisible on connect by default
                mRobot = (Sphero) robot;
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(Robot sphero) 
            {
                // let the SpheroConnectionView handle or hide it and do something here
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(Robot sphero) 
            {
                mSpheroConnectionView.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mSpheroConnectionView.startDiscovery();
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        RobotProvider.getDefaultProvider().disconnectControlledRobots();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_activity_simon, menu);
        return true;
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/R"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#262625"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivitySimon" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Green"
    android:layout_width="140.0dip"
    android:layout_height="160.0dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Red"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Yellow"
    android:background="@drawable/customgreen"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Yellow"
    android:layout_width="140.0dip"
    android:layout_height="160.0dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
    android:background="@drawable/customyellow"
    android:layout_marginTop = "3dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Scorebox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Yellow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Yellow"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Current Score: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#cccccc"
    android:textColorLink="#262625" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Scorebox"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Green"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#cccccc" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Red"
    android:layout_width="140.0dip"
    android:layout_height="160.0dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Simon"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Simon"
    android:layout_marginRight = "-50dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "-30dip"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttons" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Blue"
            android:layout_width="140.0dip"
            android:layout_height="160.0dip"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Red"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Red"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Simon"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "-50dip"
            android:background="@drawable/customblue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Simon"
            android:layout_width="100.0dip"
            android:layout_height="70.0dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/customsimon"
            android:onClick="Simonsays" />

      <orbotix.view.connection.SpheroConnectionView
            android:id="@+id/sphero_connection_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#D0000000"/>


</RelativeLayout>

    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9923
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914): Process: com.hprc.simongame, PID: 23914
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:       Couldn't load achievement_manager from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip   file "/data/app/com.hprc.simongame-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app- lib/com.hprc.simongame-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at  java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at orbotix.achievement.AchievementManager.<clinit>(AchievementManager.java:110)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at orbotix.robot.internal.DeviceConnection$DeviceSession$1$1.handleMessage(DeviceConnection.java:765)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at orbotix.robot.internal.DeviceConnection$DeviceSession$1.run(DeviceConnection.java:787)
    07-19 12:03:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(23914):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914): Activity com.hprc.simongame.MainActivitySimon has leaked IntentReceiver orbotix.robot.base.RobotProvider$1@41ff37d8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.hprc.simongame.MainActivitySimon has leaked IntentReceiver orbotix.robot.base.RobotProvider$1@41ff37d8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:805)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1559)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1539)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1533)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at orbotix.robot.base.RobotProvider.setBroadcastContext(RobotProvider.java:209)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at orbotix.robot.base.RobotProvider.startDiscovery(RobotProvider.java:236)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at orbotix.view.connection.SpheroConnectionView.setupConnectionView(SpheroConnectionView.java:254)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at orbotix.view.connection.SpheroConnectionView.startDiscovery(SpheroConnectionView.java:247)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at orbotix.view.connection.SpheroConnectionView.<init>(SpheroConnectionView.java:215)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at com.hprc.simongame.MainActivitySimon.onCreate(MainActivitySimon.java:81)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    07-19 12:03:50.876: E/ActivityThread(23914):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is bit late to comment. But because I spend a lot of time looking this answer as well, I will post my solution here. I hope people who encountered this problem could solve it now.

If you are using android studio, simply copy **armeabi** and **armeabi-v7a** to **src/main/jniLibs/**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only related to the import library to resolve just copy all folder contents Sphero-Android-SDK/library/libs to libs folder in the project target. And clean the project.